# Finding p positions with 2 subtraction sets in the take-away game

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Find the set of P-positions for the takeaway game
with the subtraction sets:
$S = {1,3,5,7}$
$S = {1,2,4,8,16,32}$
Who wins each game when there are 100 tokens on the table to start, the
first or the second player?

Would the P positions just be every position other than 6 and multiples of 6?

And would the first player always win with 100 tokens since he can just take 64 off the start leaving 36, which is a multiple of 6?

Comment: What is the "takeaway game"?  I assume it is some variant of [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) but without your telling us, it is unclear.  What is a "P-position"?  What effect do these subtraction sets have?  What would being a multiple of six have to do with winning or losing?

Comment: If the game *is* Nim, and the subtraction sets are the available options for choices of how many stones player one and player two can take on their turns respectively (player one only allowed to take values 1,3,5,7 while player 2 can take 1,2,4,8,16,32), and the last person to take a stone wins, then notice that player one may *only* take an odd number of stones on his turn.  If player two can then make the total even at the end of his turn, then on player one's turn he can only change the remaining total from even to odd and could thus never change it to zero (which is even).

Comment: similar to nim yes, the last player to take the last token wins.

Comment: p positions are those in which the player whose turn it is now is guaranteed to win when it is their turn again.

Comment: That still does not explain what the subtraction sets are.  What options are available to players on their turn?

Comment: the subtraction sets means that both players have access to both.. ie for a game with 100 tokens on their turn they can take 1,3,5,7 or any power of two amount of tokens off the board.

Comment: @JMoravitz "Subtraction games" (sometimes called "takeaway games") with their "subtraction sets" are well-known things in combinatorial game theory. For one source of background, see http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15859-f01/www/notes/comb.pdf  $P$-positions (and $N$-positions) are probably even more well known (and are also covered in that PDF): An $N$-position is a position where the Next player to move wins, and a $P$-position is a position where the next player to move loses (so that the player who moved just Previously can win). This question was pretty clear, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a player can finish his turn with the remaining number being a multiple of 6, he can guarantee to win.  Since there are no available subtraction options which are multiples of 6, and 1,2,3,4,and 5 are all options, whatever the other player does you can counteract with the appropriate number 1-5 to get it back to a multiple of 6. Therefore player 1 would be wise to take 4, 16, or 64 on his first move.

Answer (score 2):

Since the wording of the problem says "who wins ***each*** game?", I assume the question should have said "takeaway games" not "takeaway game". If that's right, then the comment "the subtraction sets means that both players have access to both.. ie for a game with 100 tokens on their turn they can take 1,3,5,7 or any power of two amount of tokens off the board." is not correct, and there are two separate questions in one:

1. What's the set of $P$-positions for the game with subtraction set $\{1,3,5,7\}$? (And so who wins with $100$ tokens?)
2. What's the set of $P$-positions for the game with subtraction set $\{1,2,4,8,16,32\}$? (And so who wins with $100$ tokens?)

The answer to **neither** of these questions is "the multiples of $6$". For example, in the first game, $4$ tokens is a $P$-position since the next player to move removes $3$ or $1$, and then other player removes the other number to win. In the second game, $3$ tokens is a $P$-position for the analogous reason with $1$ and $2$.

I would recommend writing out who wins for small numbers of tokens (maybe from $1$ to $12$ since you were already looking at multiples of $6$) for both games and seeing what pattern you find. Then see if you can prove the pattern continues (if you need to for this book/class/exercise).

---

If my first interpretation was wrong, and this is a single *partizan* subtraction game where one player has one subtraction set and the other player has the other subtraction set, then please edit your question to clarify.